# Not getting SPRING.SESSION.ID from headers

Tags: spring-websocket, spring-session

I'm using spring session and AbstractSessionWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer and am trying to create a STOMP Websocket with support for Spring Security and Spring Session. I can't seem to get my session activated. I use webstomp-client to connect (https://github.com/JSteunou/webstomp-client)

AbstractSessionWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer creates

```
@Bean
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public SessionRepositoryMessageInterceptor<S> sessionRepositoryInterceptor() {
    return new SessionRepositoryMessageInterceptor<S>(this.sessionRepository);
}
```

I pass as header to both the connect event and every message

```
SPRING.SESSION.ID:<My session id>
```

When I check the processing in SessionRepositoryMessageInterceptor, I see that it is trying to retrieve the session id through SimpMessageHeaderAccessor that expects the header to contain an object under header key simpSessionAttributes.

```
Map<String, Object> sessionHeaders = SimpMessageHeaderAccessor
            .getSessionAttributes(message.getHeaders());
    String sessionId = sessionHeaders == null ? null
            : (String) sessionHeaders.get(SPRING_SESSION_ID_ATTR_NAME);
```

All the attributes that SimpMessageHeaderAccessor seems to expect are not present in the stomp client and just seem to belong to a different protocol.

How do I deal with activating a session under Stomp, Spring WebSocket, Spring Security and Spring Session? Or more specifically:

- Why does SessionRepositoryMessageInterceptor use SimpleHeaderAccessor in stead of StompHeaderAcessor?
- What headers do I need to pass from a javascript client to create a session (assuming I received the session id through traditional login)?

Comment: I wonder if there is a scenario under which AbstractSessionWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer and webstomp-client can work together. At this point, I don't think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the issue is but I can explain a few things to help you debug the issue.

Spring supports WebSocket-scoped attributes. Those are attributes that exist for as long as the session exists. The SessionRepositoryMessageInterceptor, as a HandshakeInterceptor, hooks into the initial HTTP handshake request and saves the SPRING.SESSION.ID as a WebSocket-scoped attribute. Then after the handshake, when STOMP messages start to flow, it intercepts every incoming message, and retrieves the SPRING.SESSION.ID in the websocket attributes. So I am not sure why you're trying to pass SPRING.SESSION.ID as a header. That's all managed for you as I just explained and associated with the WebSocket session.

As for the question about SimpHeaderAccessor vs StompHeaderAcessor, the former is a more generalized version. It's not wrong to use it as long it gives you enough information. In this case Spring Session doesn't care for STOMP specific details.

I don't understand your second question about what headers need to be passed from a javascript client to create a session. As long as the HTTP handshake is made within the same HTTP session it should just work. There is nothing different here from how you would do any HTTP call.

Comment: Also you have seen the samples https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/tree/master/samples/websocket ?

Comment: I notice in one of your other posts that you're setting sessionCookieNeeded=false for your SockJS configuration. That could explain your issues, if the cookie that indicates you jsessionid isn't getting passed to the server.

Comment: Thanks for your insights. It could be my inexperience in this area, but didn't think I would be able to use cookies in a mobile app scenario.

Comment: I'm just not sure how to initialize the session since during the initial handshake stomp doesn't seem to allow any custom headers. So, I can't pass the SPRING.SESSION.ID there as a header (but it does allow them in subsequent messages). If it is indeed possible to pass a cookie, I could pass it like that. It's just that I'm not on a browser, so not sure how that works. But it offers a direction of exploration

Comment: Ok, you were right: I could initiate the session through the cookie! Great!

So, now my second question is. What is the suggested solution for allowing the user to automatically login, remember me cookie?

Funny, I fully expected the whole interaction to work through headers.

Comment: Are you sure the /ws/websocket endpoint accepts and receives cookies? My cookies are passed through nginx I see them coming in when I hit the /login endpoint, but not when I hit the websocket CONNECT endpoint

Comment: The endpoint is just another HTTP URL that hits the Servlet container. I really don't understand your question. There is no magic here.

Comment: Ok, thx. I will consider this a answered and post any additional questions separately.